# Resizing and Redrawing Canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I am currently trying to display images on a canvas. More specifically, I would like to have the images that are drawn on the canvas to be resized based on the size of the window (this way the images are always going to fit on the canvas).

I start off with a simple canvas that fills the entire screen.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

I then get set up with my background images and images that will be able to get resized on the background.

```
backgroundImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("filepath"))
image1 = Image.open("filepath")
image2 = ...
....
....
```

I then created a method for resizing the images.

```
"""
This method resizes a image so that all the images fits on the GUI. This first creates an Image object,
but since the Image object does not allow access to the width and height of the Image object, a ImageTk
object needs to be created from the Image object. The ImageTk object cannot resize, but the Image object
can. So using ImageTk object to get the height and width and the Image object to resize, a new Image object
that is resized to fit the GUI is created.
@imageFile- the image file that is being resized
@windowMeasure- the measurement of the window to proportionally resize the image
@useHeight- determine the measurement being proportioned
"""
def resizedImageTk(image, windowMeasure, useHeight):
    imageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    area = windowMeasure * 4/5
    tileSize = area / 4
    if useHeight:
        proportion = tileSize / imageTk.height()
    else:
        proportion = tileSize / imageTk.width()
    resizedImage = image.resize((int(imageTk.width()*proportion), int(imageTk.height()*proportion)))
    resizedImageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedImage)
    return resizedImageTk
```

I then use a method for redrawing the resized images when there is a change to the size of the window and bind it to the root. Note: I know that this can be extremely computational and so I have reduced the number of times this occurs

```
numResizes = 0
def handle_configure(event):
    if numResizes % 5 == 0:
        geometry = root.geometry()
        width = int(geometry[0:geometry.index("x")])
        height = int(geometry[geometry.index("x")+1:geometry.index("+")])
        canvas.create_image((0,0), image=backgroundImageTk, anchor="nw")

        if height < width:
            measurement = height
        else:
            measurement = width

        resizedImage1 = resizedImageTk(image1, measurement, height < width)
        resizedImage2 = ....
        ....
        ....

   
        images = [resizedImage1, resizedImage2, ...]
    
        imageWidth = resizedImage1.width()
        imageHeight = resizedImage1.height()
    
        i = 0
        for row in range(0, int(len(images) / 4)):
            for column in range(0, int(len(images) / 5):
                x = imageWidth*column + int(width/2) - imageWidth * 2
                y = imageHeight*row + int(height/2) - int(imageHeight*2.5)
                canvas.create_image((x, y), image=images[i])
                i=i+1
    numResizes = numResizes + 1  
root.bind("<Configure>", handle_configure)
root.mainloop()
```

I have run this with my images and have had some success, however, it does not work completely. I have my background image get displayed but my other images do not. I do not know why since when I use the create_line function for the canvas in the nested for loop (where the images are not being shown), I do get the line showing.

If someone could give some advice on this, I would appreciate it!

Thanks

***Update:***

Here is a simple sample of what I am trying to do. You can use any sample image to test this.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = int(root.winfo_screenwidth() * 103/104), int(root.winfo_screenheight() * 11/12)
root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

testImage = Image.open("enter file path here!")
testImageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(testImage)

resizedTestImage = None
resizedTestImageTk = None

def handle_configure(event):
    geometry = root.geometry()
    width = int(geometry[0:geometry.index("x")])
    height = int(geometry[geometry.index("x")+1:geometry.index("+")])
    
    useHeight = height < width
    if useHeight:
        measurement = height
    else:
        measurement = width

    if useHeight:
        proportion = measurement / testImageTk.height()
    else:
        proportion = measurement / testImageTk.width()
    
    resizedTestImage = testImage.resize((int(testImageTk.width()*proportion), int(testImageTk.height()*proportion)))
    resizedTestImageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedTestImage)
    canvas.create_image((0,0), image=resizedTestImageTk, anchor="nw")
    print("(image width, image height): (" + str(resizedTestImageTk.width()) + " " + str(resizedTestImageTk.height()) + ")")

root.bind("<Configure>", handle_configure)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `<Configure>` can be executed even when you only move window - you could use `event.width, event.height` and compare with previous value `event.width, event.height` to recognize if window was resized.

Comment: maybe you have problem with bug in PhotoImage which removes images from memory when it is assigned to local variable -  you may have to assign images to global variables or to variables in some class. See **Note** at the end of page [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: The thing is that the information for the image (width and height) are still there (I have tested printing the coordinates which use the width and height of the image). It might be that the information of the pixels (color) in the image is cleared. I guess I could just un-DRY my code if that is the issue. I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: as I said `PhotoImage` has `bug` which removes image from memory and you maybe get empty image.

Comment: Well, I have tried just about everything, and still no luck. I first did everything inside the handle_configure method and that did not work. I then went to the extent of having all of the information (ImageTk object, resized Image object, and resized ImageTk object) stored as global variables and that still did not work.

Comment: your code seems OK but we can't run it to see what can be wrong. Better create minimal working code - you could even add some small image in question - ie. [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) - and then we can download image and copy code to test it.

Comment: Alright, I have a basic set up where there is just one image that gets resized based on the size of the window (I used the image that you were referring to, so you only need to change the file path to where ever you have it stored). This still does not work on my end. I do not know what is the best way to send it since it is longer than what a comment will allow. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: never put code in comment - it will be not readble. Edit question and append new code at the end of question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227747/discussion-between-ehren-and-furas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new code has problem with bug in `PhotoImage`.

Inside `handle_configure` you assign to local variable `resizedTestImageTk` even if you already created external/global variable `resizedTestImageTk`

It works for me if I inform function that it has to use `global` to inform function that it has to assign it to external variable instead of local one

```
def handle_configure(event):
    global resizedTestImageTk   # <-- inform function to assign image to global variable instead of using local one
```

or I assign local `resizedTestImageTk` to global class.

```
canvas.resizedTestImageTk = resizedTestImageTk   # <-- assign local `resizedTestImageTk` to global class.
```

---

Minimal working code.

I changed some calculations to make it more readable.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- functions ---

def handle_configure(event):
    global resizedTestImageTk   # <-- inform function to assign image to global variable instead of using local one
    
    geometry = root.geometry()    
    window_width  = int(geometry[0:geometry.index("x")])
    window_height = int(geometry[geometry.index("x")+1:geometry.index("+")])
    
    image_width  = testImageTk.height()
    image_height = testImageTk.width()
    
    if window_height < window_width:
        proportion = window_height / image_height
    else:
        proportion = window_width / image_width
     
    image_width  = int(image_width  * proportion)
    image_height = int(image_height * proportion)
    
    resizedTestImage   = testImage.resize((image_width, image_height))
    resizedTestImageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedTestImage)
    canvas.create_image((0,0), image=resizedTestImageTk, anchor="nw")
    #canvas.resizedTestImageTk = resizedTestImageTk   # <-- assign local `resizedTestImageTk` to global class.

    print(f"(image width, image height): ({image_width} {image_height})")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
WIDTH =  int(root.winfo_screenwidth() * 103/104)
HEIGHT = int(root.winfo_screenheight() * 11/12)

root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

testImage = Image.open("lenna.png")
testImageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(testImage)

resizedTestImage = None
resizedTestImageTk = None

root.bind("<Configure>", handle_configure)

root.mainloop()
```

And image for test

[image]

Wikipedia: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna)

---

**EDIT:**

I see other problem - not so visible. You always put new image on but you don't remove old image - so finally it may use more memory.

You could put image on canvas at start - and get its ID

```
image_id = canvas.create_image((0,0), image=testImageTk, anchor="nw")
```

and later replace image using ID

```
canvas.itemconfig(image_id, image=resizedTestImageTk)
```

Minimale working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- functions ---

def handle_configure(event):
    global resizedTestImageTk   # <-- inform function to assign image to global variable instead of using local one
    
    geometry = root.geometry()    
    window_width  = int(geometry[0:geometry.index("x")])
    window_height = int(geometry[geometry.index("x")+1:geometry.index("+")])
    
    image_width = testImageTk.width()
    image_height = testImageTk.height()
    
    if window_height < window_width:
        proportion = window_height / image_width
    else:
        proportion = window_width / image_height

    image_width  = int(image_width  * proportion)
    image_height = int(image_height * proportion)
    
    resizedTestImage = testImage.resize((image_width, image_height))
    resizedTestImageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedTestImage)
    
    canvas.itemconfig(image_id, image=resizedTestImageTk)

    #canvas.resizedTestImageTk = resizedTestImageTk   # <-- assign local `resizedTestImageTk` to global class.


    print(f"(image width, image height): ({image_width} {image_height})")

# --- main ---

image_id = None # default value at start

root = tk.Tk()

WIDTH =  int(root.winfo_screenwidth() * 103/104)
HEIGHT = int(root.winfo_screenheight() * 11/12)

root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

testImage = Image.open("lenna.png")
testImageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(testImage)

resizedTestImage = None
resizedTestImageTk = None

image_id = canvas.create_image((0,0), image=testImageTk, anchor="nw")

root.bind("<Configure>", handle_configure)

root.mainloop()
```