# Can't properly set an image as canvas background in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my Tkinter window to have four buttons, each with its own background image, disposed as a 2x2 grid. I tried using frames but you can't set an image as frame background so I had to switch to Canvas. This is the code for one of the four blocks.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x200")
root.wm_title("KnowYourArt")

styles_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/styles_bg.png"))
canvas_styles = Canvas(root)
bg = canvas_styles.create_image(100, 100, image=styles_bg)

width = 4
height = 2
Button(canvas_styles, text="Styles", width=width, height=height).pack(side=TOP)
Label(canvas_styles, text="Gain info about styles").pack(side=BOTTOM)
canvas_styles.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

In my intentions, the background image dimensions should cover both the button and the label, and the image's dimensions should be independent from the dimensions of the widgets. Instead, I obtain a canvas where the height of the BG image is the same as the height of the button, and the width is the same as the label's width. I tried many alternative possibilities, including setting a width and height for the canvas, and none of them properly worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is unusual to pack or grid widgets onto a canvas. The canonical way to do so is to use `create_window`. Also note that an image dimensions are not dependent upon the canvas dimensions. Therefore you need to resize or supsample the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing and Redrawing Canvas in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866101/resizing-and-redrawing-canvas-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

width = 4
height = 1

def add_canvas(frame, img, x, y, text):
    c = Canvas(frame, width=300, height=300)
    c.focus()
    c.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    bg = c.create_image(x, y, image=img)
    btn = Button(frame, text="Go!", width=width, height=height)
    c.create_text(150, 190, text=text, font=('Helvetica', 15), fill='white')
    c.create_window(100, 200, anchor="nw", window=btn)
    return c

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.wm_title("Title")

f_1 = Frame(root)
f_2 = Frame(root)
f_3 = Frame(root)
f_4 = Frame(root)

bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/im1.png"))
bg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/im2.png"))
bg3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/im3.png"))
bg4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/im4.jpg"))

canvas_1 = add_canvas(f_1, bg1, 0, 0, "foo")
canvas_2 = add_canvas(f_2, bg2, 240, 240, "foo")
canvas_3 = add_canvas(f_3, bg3, 120, 120, "foo")
canvas_4 = add_canvas(f_4, bg4, 100, 100, "foo")
f_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
f_2.grid(row=0, column=1)
f_3.grid(row=1, column=0)
f_4.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

And here's the output
[image]